# What does it mean when we elude ourselves?

Tags: meaning

Here is a sentence:
In our daily lives, then, we are never quite there. In the present we **elude ourselves** and the world eludes the grasp of a fully self-possessed experience.

Comment: Please give us the source of the sentence that so that we understand the context.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is a typo or misunderstanding, and that what was meant to be said (or actually said) was that we ***delude*** ourselves.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is about psychological idea of being here and now.

When we're here and now, we are **quite there**.
When we are not here and not now, we **elude ourselves**...